# How do I read a distinct key value pair of a json response?

Tags: python, json, api, google-maps-api-3

This problem drives me crazy:

I request a google api to get a json response with distances and durations. But I can't access a distinct key value pair of this json response. I get a Type Error object is not subscriptable.

```
import requests
import json
link = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/...'
gmaps_json = requests.get(link).json()
```

I receive the following json response:

```
{'destination_addresses': ['XXXXXX 3, 30165 Hannover, Germany'], 'origin_addresses': ['XXXXX 17, XXXXX XXXXXX, Germany'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '196 km', 'value': 196077}, 'duration': {'text': '2 hours 10 mins', 'value': 7821}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

I want to access the 'rows', I've already tried:

```
gmaps_json['rows'] 
gmaps_json[3]
```

But always TypeError 'NoneType' is not subscriptable

Comment: with the above json, for me :print(gmaps_json['rows']) works fine

Comment: Is it a conversion error in this line maybe? 
`gmaps_json = requests.get(link).json()`

Answer (score 0):

Again, with the JSON you supply i am able to parse everything fine. Here a small example to help you.

```
gmaps_json = {'destination_addresses': ['XXXXXX 3, 30165 Hannover, Germany'], 'origin_addresses': ['XXXXX 17, XXXXX XXXXXX, Germany'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '196 km', 'value': 196077}, 'duration': {'text': '2 hours 10 mins', 'value': 7821}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}

print("Distance : {}".format(gmaps_json['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']))
print("Duration : {}".format(gmaps_json['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']))
print("Status : {}".format(gmaps_json['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status']))
```